# Where can I find a copy of Bérard-Bergery's lecture notes on quaternionic manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, quaternionic-geometry

In the 1970's, Bérard-Bergery proved certain results on quaternionic Kähler manifolds, some of which are explained in the book *Einstein Manifolds* by Besse. Several times, Besse's book references a set of unpublished lecture notes by Bérard-Bergery for these results ([BéBer 7] in the book):

> L. Bérard Bergery, Variétés quaternionniennes, Notes d'une conference a la table ronde "Varietes d'Einstein", Espalion (1979). (Unpublished).

I am looking for a copy of these lecture notes but was unfortunately unable to find any. Would anyone here have any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Since no one on here has responded I would advise contacting someone at Université de Lorraine, from which Bergery retired in 2010. It would be preferable to find someone in his field which held a position at the same time as he, they may have a copy they can scan, if not inquire if they could point you to some of his old conference pals that would surely have a copy